# is there anyway we can add curved polylines in azure maps js

Tags: azure-maps

I used offset property of linelayer in azure maps but it didn't worked

```
 var polylines = new atlas.layer.LineLayer(datasource2, null, {
        strokeColor: 'DarkOrchid',
        strokeWidth: ['sqrt',['sqrt',['to-number',  ['get', 'count']]]]
        ,
        filter: ['any', ['==', ['geometry-type'], 'LineString'], ['==', ['geometry-type'], 'MultiLineString']],
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

I added a large code sample here https://samples.azuremaps.com/?sample=curved-lines that shows several different ways of adding curves in Azure Maps.

**Original response**

To curve a line there is a couple of options. If you want the line to follow the curvature of the earth, you can calculate the coordinates that form a geodesic path. There is a built-in method of this in the `atlas.math` namespace called [getGeodesicPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-maps-control/atlas.math?view=azure-maps-typescript-latest#azure-maps-control-atlas-math-getgeodesicpath). For example:

```js
var line = new atlas.data.LineString([[-74.00667,40.754572],[-42.75286,-22.752037]]);

//Convert the coordinates to create a curved geodesic path.
line.coordinates = atlas.math.getGeodesicPath(line);

//Add line to data source.
datasource.add(line);
```

Comment: getGeodesicPath this function just adds more coordinates in linestring . it is not making any curved line

Comment: The is no curved line class in Azure Maps. Circles are generally approximated when rendered, by using a handful of calculated points.

Comment: then how we can add curved linestring in azure maps

Comment: If you want curved paths you need to calculate a set of points that approximate the curve. For full circles, use `atlas.math.getGeodesicPath` if you want the line to curve follow the shortest path on a globe (mercator path). For other curves you can use a cardinal spline `atlas.math.getCardinalSpline` here are some samples https://samples.azuremaps.com/?search=curve Here are the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-maps-control/atlas.math?view=azure-maps-typescript-latest#azure-maps-control-atlas-math-getcardinalspline